# How to extract distinct values from a mongo database using Waterline and Sails.js (version 0.10)?

Tags: mongodb, distinct, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Using `Sails.js` version `0.10.x`, assume I have a model `Dog`, populated as follows (writtenout in `yaml` format for convenience, but in my case it's actually in a `mongo` database.)

```
dogs:
-  breed: "wolf"
   name: "Fido"
-  breed: "wolf"
   name: "Roger"
-  breed: "dingo"
   name: "Nipper"
-  breed: "dingo"
   name: "Ernie"
-  breed: "corgi"
   name: "Bernadi"
-  breed: "corgi"
   name: "Queenie"
-  breed: "poodle"
   name: "Christopher"
-  breed: "poodle"
   name: "Tony"

etc
```

So now I want to create a list of the available breeds.

```
Dog.find().exec(err, dogs) {
  breeds = [];
  dogs.each(function(dog)) {
    if (breeds.indexOf(dog.breed) === -1) breeds.push(dog.breed);
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this with fewer hits on the database? Something like

```
Dog.find().distinct('breed').exec(function(err, breeds){
  ...
});
```

I've found [this closed Waterline issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/60) which seems to indicate that I could use a `.distinct` method but I tried it and alas no dice.

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'distinct'
```

How might I go about this in a database efficient manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For these kind of queries you can use use `native` method to execute raw MongoDB command:

```
Dog.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.distinct('breed', function(err, dogs) {
        // do something here
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice - thanks. Much faster too.  0.037 seconds to query 16,000 records.